# Report Contains PC model, OS and last installed security patch

Tags: reporting-services, sccm

I used Configuration Manager 2006 and I want to receive a report that cotains PC model, OS and last installed security patch. Are there any reports that fits this requiremens in reports section in SCCM or should I have to write query? if it so, I need help for query.

any help is greatly appreciated!

thank you all

Comment: Might be a better question for the https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com/ communities

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it help. You can change and V_UpdateInfo.Title Like '%security%' and V_UpdateInfo.DateCreated BETWEEN GetDATE() - 70 and GetDATE() and FCM.CollectionID='xxxxxxx':

```
    SELECT v_R_System.name0 as 'Name',
       v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Model0 as 'Model',
       v_RA_System_ResourceNames.Resource_Names0 as 'FQDN',
       v_R_System.Resource_Domain_OR_Workgr0 as 'DOMAIN',
       v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.Caption0 as 'Operating System',
       dbo.vSMS_CombinedDeviceResources.ClientState as 'Pending restart',
       (
       SELECT CASE [ClientState] 
            WHEN '0' THEN 'Reboot no needed' WHEN '1' THEN 'Reboot init: Configuration Manager' WHEN '2' THEN 'File Rename' WHEN '3' THEN 'Reboot init: Configuration Manager, File Rename' WHEN '4' THEN 'Reboot init: Windows Update'
            WHEN '5' THEN 'Reboot init: Configuration Manager, Reboot init: Windows Update' WHEN '6' THEN 'File Rename, Reboot init: Windows Update' WHEN '7' THEN 'Reboot init: Configuration Manager, File Rename, Reboot init: Windows Update' 
            WHEN '8' THEN 'Add or Remove Feature' WHEN '9' THEN 'Reboot init: Configuration Manager, Add or Remove Feature' WHEN '10' THEN 'File Rename, Add or Remove Feature'
            WHEN '11' THEN 'Reboot init: Configuration Manager, File Rename, Add or Remove Feature' WHEN '12' THEN 'Reboot init: Windows Update, Add or Remove Feature' 
            WHEN '13' THEN 'Reboot init: Configuration Manager, Reboot init: Windows Update, Add or Remove Feature' WHEN '14' THEN 'File Rename, Reboot init: Windows Update, Add or Remove Feature'
            WHEN '15' THEN 'Reboot init: Configuration Manager, File Rename, Reboot init: Windows Update, Add or Remove Feature' ELSE 'Unknown' END AS Expr1) AS [Pending restart details]
          , V_UpdateInfo.ArticleID
          , CASE 
                WHEN v_Update_ComplianceStatus.Status = '2' THEN 'MISSING'
                WHEN v_Update_ComplianceStatus.Status = '3' THEN 'INSTALLED'
              ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
              END AS 'PatchStatus'
           , V_UpdateInfo.DateCreated
           , V_UpdateInfo.Title
           , V_UpdateInfo.InfoURL
           , V_R_System.ResourceID
           , MAX(SDN.System_OU_Name0) as PathDN
FROM v_R_System
left join v_Update_ComplianceStatus on v_R_System.ResourceID = v_Update_ComplianceStatus.ResourceID
left join v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM on v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID
left join dbo.vSMS_CombinedDeviceResources on v_R_System.ResourceID = dbo.vSMS_CombinedDeviceResources.MachineID
left join V_UpdateInfo on v_Update_ComplianceStatus.CI_ID = V_UpdateInfo.CI_ID
left join v_RA_System_ResourceNames on v_R_System.ResourceID = v_RA_System_ResourceNames.ResourceID
left join v_UpdateScanStatus on v_R_System.ResourceID = v_UpdateScanStatus.ResourceID
left join v_GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS on v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS.ResourceID
left Join v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM on v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.ResourceID
left join v_FullCollectionMembership fcm on v_R_System.ResourceID=fcm.ResourceId
join v_RA_System_SystemOUName SDN on v_R_System.ResourceID=SDN.ResourceID


WHERE V_UpdateInfo.DateCreated BETWEEN GetDATE() - 70 and GetDATE()

and v_UpdateInfo.IsDeployed = '1' 
and v_UpdateInfo.CIType_ID = '8'
and V_UpdateInfo.Title Like '%security%'
and FCM.CollectionID='xxxxxxx'

GROUP BY 

v_R_System.name0, 
v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Model0,
V_UpdateInfo.DateCreated,
v_RA_System_ResourceNames.Resource_Names0,
v_R_System.Resource_Domain_OR_Workgr0,
v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.Caption0,
dbo.vSMS_CombinedDeviceResources.ClientState,
V_UpdateInfo.ArticleID,
v_Update_ComplianceStatus.Status,
V_UpdateInfo.Title,
V_UpdateInfo.InfoURL,
v_R_System.ResourceID

ORDER BY 
v_R_System.name0, 
V_UpdateInfo.DateCreated, 
MAX(SDN.System_OU_Name0)
```